# Conditional .htaccess 404 DirectoryIndex

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

Is it possible to change the DirectoryIndex in .htaccess in the event of a 404?  I have a scenario where if there is a 404 I want to change the DirectoryIndex to index.htm instead of index.php.  By default though I have to declare DirectoryIndex in .htaccess  so I am looking for something like an if else statement.

```
if 404
then DirectoryIndex=index.htm
else
then DirectoryIndex=index.php
```

is this possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

set Custom Error page in your .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.htm
```